# Identifying a thread

Tags: c++, multithreading

To identify a thread, we must do the following:
1) Get and save its id.
2) Within a function running in the thread, get the thread's id again and compare it with the saved id.

Eg: http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/8f608dff835f96d0
(The program is from Josuttis' book "The C++ Standard Library", 2nd Ed.)

```
thread::id master_tid {};

/// declarations
void doSomething();


int main()  
{
   thread master {doSomething};
   master_tid = master.get_id();

   thread slave {doSomething};

   /// ...

   /// join with threads
   master.join();
   slave.join();

   cout << "done" << endl;
}


void doSomething()
{
   if (this_thread::get_id() == master_tid)
      cout << "master thread ..."
           << endl;
   else
      cout << "NOT master thread ..."
           << endl;

   /// ...
}
```

The output is:

```
master thread ...
NOT master thread ...
done
```

However, the above scheme works only IF there is no delay between invoking the doSomething() function and saving the master thread’s id.

If such a delay is introduced, the doSomething() function won't be able to discriminate between the master thread and any other, since, when it runs, the master thread's id hasn't *yet* been saved in the referenced variable.
Eg: http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/0bff325f872ba9c2

```
thread::id master_tid {};

/// declarations
void doSomething();


int main()  
{
   thread master {doSomething};
   thread slave {doSomething};

   /// delay
   this_thread::sleep_for(seconds {1});

   master_tid = master.get_id();

   /// ...

   /// join with threads
   master.join();
   slave.join();

   cout << "done" << endl;
}


void doSomething()
{
   /// ...
}
```

Now, because of the delay, the output is as follows:

```
NOT master thread ...
NOT master thread ...
done
```

Therefore, I'd like to ask, how can we make this scheme work perfectly? Do we need to use condition variables to communicate between the main thread and the other threads, indicating if the thread id has been saved?

Or, is there some simpler way?

Comment: Pass a parameter to doSomething

Comment: It is a basic threading race bug, you cannot assume your main thread has progressed far enough to assign the variable.  Using sleep_for() only helps to make it more obvious that the bug exists, if the machine is busy then it happens even without the sleep.  Synchronization required.  An ismaster argument would trivially solve it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

All threads have to wait until the `master_tid` is assigned. Instead of manual `sleep_for`, which is error prone and will eventually lead to bugs in your program, you should use a synchronization mechanism. In your case, where you want all threads wait for a condition, you can use a condition variable. [However, I would just pass different functions to master and slave, or pass a parameter.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49424032/2169853)

```
#include <thread>
#include <mutex>
#include <condition_variable>

std::mutex m;
std::condition_variable cv;
thread::id master_tid {};
bool ready = false;

/// declarations
void doSomething() {
    std::unique_lock<std::mutex> lk(m);
    cv.wait(lk, []{return ready;});

    // master_tid is now assigned
   if (this_thread::get_id() == master_tid)
      cout << "master thread ..."
           << endl;
   else
      cout << "NOT master thread ..."
           << endl;
}


int main()  
{
   thread master {doSomething};

   thread slave {doSomething};

    {
        std::lock_guard<std::mutex> lk(m);
        ready = true;
        master_tid = master.get_id();
    }
    cv.notify_all();

   /// ...

   /// join with threads
   master.join();
   slave.join();

   cout << "done" << endl;
}
```

Comment: I have used the technique suggested by you, to get a working [solution](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/d3cfe3ea888e618c)

Comment: I should have guessed you wouldn't wait :)

Answer (score 1):

This problem is trivially solved with `std::future`.

example:

```
#include <future>
#include <thread>
#include <functional>
#include <iostream>

/// declarations
void doSomething(std::shared_future<std::thread::id> future_master_thread);


int main()  
{
    std::promise<std::thread::id> promise_master_thread;
    auto shared_master_thread = promise_master_thread.get_future().share();
    std::thread master {std::bind(doSomething, shared_master_thread)};
    promise_master_thread.set_value(master.get_id());

    std::thread slave {std::bind(doSomething, shared_master_thread)};

   /// ...

   /// join with threads
   master.join();
   slave.join();

   std::cout << "done" << std::endl;
}


void doSomething(std::shared_future<std::thread::id> future_master_thread)
{
   if (std::this_thread::get_id() == future_master_thread.get())
      std::cout << "master thread ..."
           << std::endl;
   else
      std::cout << "NOT master thread ..."
           << std::endl;

   /// ...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure I understand the question completely, but isn't it possible to pass the executed function an additional parameter which defines if it the master thread or not?

```
void doSomething(bool isMaster) {
    if (isMaster)
      cout << "master thread ..."
           << endl;
   else
      cout << "NOT master thread ..."
           << endl;
}

std::thread master = std::thread(doSomething, true);
std::thread slave = std::thread(doSomething, false);
```

Personally I would split `doSomething` into a general part and a specific part and then either create special functions for master and slave or define it in a lambda.

```
std::thread master = std::thread([]() {
    doMasterStuff();
    doSomething();
});

std::thread slave([]() {
    doSlaveStuff();
    doSomething();
});
```

Or I would use the template method pattern

```
class ThreadFunction {
private:
    void doSpecific() = 0;
    void doSomething() { ... }
public:
    void operator()() {
        doSpecific();
        doSomething();
     }
};

class MasterThread: public ThreadFunc {
     void doSpecific() {
          cout << "master thread ..."
               << endl;
     }
};
```

Or create a class which gets the specific part as a "strategy".

```
template<typename T>
class ThreadFunc2 {
private:
    T specific;
    void doSomething() { ... };
public:
    ThreadFunc2(T s): specific( std::move(s) ) {}
    void operator()() {
        specific();
        doSomething();
    }
};

std::thread master([]() {          
    cout << "master thread ..." << endl;
});
```

Answer (score 0):

In fact your problem is that you crate 2 threads and you compare their id to a none initialized value.

Indeed we have a look to the scheduling

```
--------------------------------------------> main time 
     |       |        |          | 
   master  slave     sleep      attribute id
--------------------------------------------> master time 
        |
      do_something
--------------------------------------------> slave time
                |
             do_something
```

A way to make them able to see if they are master or salve is to use a bool that tells is the master or the salve has been identified.

```
int main()  
{
   bool know_master = false;
   thread master {doSomething};
   thread slave {doSomething};

   /// delay
   this_thread::sleep_for(seconds {1});

   master_tid = master.get_id();
   know_master = true;

   /// ...

   /// join with threads
   master.join();
   slave.join();

   cout << "done" << endl;
}


void doSomething()
{
   while (! know_master) {
        //sleep here
   }
   if (this_thread::get_id() == master_tid)
      cout << "master thread ..."
           << endl;
   else
      cout << "NOT master thread ..."
           << endl;

   /// ...
}
```

Comment: `know_master` should be a shared variable. You probably need some form of synchronization or use atomics.

Comment: Whenever I see explicit sleeps in threading code I have a feeling that this is incorrect. Why don't you use e.g. a condition variable?

Comment: No, I mean a condition variable (http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/condition_variable)

Comment: With a condition variable it's more elegant and faster. You can modify my answer by adding that (I never used a condition variable in cpp). Also it is not needed because you set the master id before updating the boolean

Comment: An explicit synchronization is mandatory for correctness. Right now, the compiler would be free to move the assignments to `master_tid` and `know_master` around, e.g. swap them or even before `sleep_for`. It may also happen that threads do not see the assignments, or just one of them. Doing synchronization without synchronization functions defined in the memory model will always be incorrect. Additionally, manual sleeping will sometimes fail depending on scheduling in the OS.

Answer (score 0):

#### Identifying a thread *on Linux*

In addition to other answers, on Linux (specifically), you could identify a thread by using first [pthread_setname_np(3)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/pthread_setname_np.3.html) (near the start of the thread's function) and `pthread_getname_np` afterwards. You can also get a unique tid with the [gettid(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/gettid.2.html) syscall (which returns some unique integer).

The disadvantage of `pthread_getname_np` is that you have to call `pthread_setname_np` once before (for your own explicitly created threads, it is easy; for threads created by some library, it is harder).

The disadvantage of `gettid` is that it is not wrapped by the C library. However, that wrapping is trivial to code:

```
static inline pid_t mygettid(void) { return syscall(SYS_gettid, 0L); }
```

You need [syscall(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/syscall.2.html) and `<sys/syscall.h>`

Both `pthread_getname_np` and `gettid` may be Linux specific, but they can be used to uniquely identify your thread.

#### general hints about threads

As a rule of thumb, you'll better pass some thread-unique data at thread creation time e.g. to [pthread_create(3)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/pthread_create.3.html) or as explicit (second and more) argument to [`std::thread`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/thread/thread) constructor, notably if you want to use `pthread_setname_np` in your thread's function (and in most other cases).

So you would declare `void doSomething(int);` and do construct your threads using

```
 thread master {doSomething,10};
 thread slave {doSomething,42};
```

The choice of 10 and 42 is arbitrary, and you might declare instead something like 
 `void doSomething(std::string)` and then have 
 `thread master {doSomething, std::string{"masterth"}};` etc...